# How can I count docs in find in Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to count docs in mongodb request.

I can count `count = docs.length` in `toArray()`-s callback but allways gives `10`. A can do 2 same requests just replace `find` to `count` but it seems wrong

```
let count;
  db.get().collection('images').find({
     $and: [
     {tags: { $in: tags }}, 
     {date: {$gte: date.toISOString()}}, 
     {title:{$regex: query, $options: "$i"}}, 
  ]},
  (err, docs)=>{docs.toArray((err, res)=>{
    count= res.length
  })}
)
  .skip(0).limit(10).toArray((err, docs)=>{    
    res = {data:docs, dataLength:count }
    cb(err, res);
// })   
});
```

I am getting this err: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably always receiving 10 back because you are specifically saying "give me 10 back" when you do `.limit(10)`. Now, the reason you are getting that error is because `.skip` has to be added to the end of the `.find()`. This is what your query should look like:

```
db.collection('images').find({
  $and: [
    {tags: { $in: tags }}, 
    {date: {$gte: date.toISOString()}}, 
    {title:{$regex: query, $options: "$i"}},
  ]
}).skip(0).limit(10).toArray((err, docs) => {
  if (err) { console.log(err) }
  else {
    let res = {data:docs, dataLength:docs.length}
    // do any other logic here
  }
})
```